# Selenium IDE - [error] Element css=button.ng-binding.active not found

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying a basic webpage navigation and each time, I run the recorded scrip it throws the error as defined in the title.

Environment - Selenium IDE - 2.9.1
Browser - Mozilla

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/samplequestions</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button.ng-binding.active</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button.ng-binding</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button.ng-binding</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//button[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=myrate</td>
    <td>1000</td>
```

Could someone help me out what I may have to change ?

Comment: There could be no elements with class `active` in initial page source. This class name could be added when element is selected(highlighted), like when you make mouse right-click on it

Comment: What should we do in such cases, I checked the source code, there is a Button Class, any suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: Should I give a ClickandWait command before the next command is run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as now 'ng-binding' is an AngularJS locator and selenium doesn't support it.
If you need to automate Angular application then it is better to you Protrator and using it you can find element like this:

element(by.binding('value'));

Comment: Thanks Kuba, looks like worth a try!